# Run away button javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys im trying to create a RUN away BUTTON that whe hoverd it run away.
I found some nice ideas on the internet but mainly only in JQuery and im trying to do it in JS.
This is what i have so far

```
function moveButton() {
let randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - 100));
button.animate({ "left": randX + "px" }, { duration: 1500 });

}

button.addEventListener('mousemove', moveButton);
```

The main problem im having is that it keeps returning automatically to the original position, and that doesnt make it look nice.

I tried the .pause() method but im not quite sure how to make it work.
Any help is apreciated.

Comment: I don’t think mousemove is a thing.  Try `mouseenter` or `mouseover`

Comment: Ive tried changing the mouse events to several diferent, and your right the mouseover one seems to be the best, but the problem continues, for some reason the button returns to its original position.

Comment: If you want the button to in place, you will have to add the css to keep it there.  I'm not quite sure I understand exactly what you want.  Also - problems with your code are as follows:  `button` is not defined and `animate` is a jQuery method - not a native javascript method.

Comment: The animate method works as Native JavaScript method :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate.
I just dont know how i can get it to stop at the new location.
If you wanna check this is the Game i made:https://catch-the-frog.netlify.app/
If you see once the moveButton function is called the frog moves, but as soon as its finishes the animation, it goes back to the starting position, and i dont understand why.